# Running faye server with nginx and passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, faye

I have successfully installed number of rails applications with nginx and passenger, but with a faye application i don't know what should be:

1. Nginx conf for a faye application, A nice self-explanatory tutorial will suffice.
2. List of things that I need to have installed to run faye server
3. Is it mandatory to open `443`(https) port for the server and is port `9292` not needed?
4. Do i run faye server from rackup command in a screen or not? If no, what root do i set in nginx conf for nginx to know the start point?
5. How does thin server come into play? Is it needed to run?

I followed [this](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-private-pub-on-heroku/) tutorial to make my faye app. So far I have been using it through heroku, but due to latency issues I have to move to a server in the local region

Here's an example to a deployed [faye app](http://ramfayeserver.herokuapp.com/) .

So far I have faye app, passenger and nginx installed on the server(centos). I am just looking for answers to above questions to proceed further. Please help Thanks in advance